# change the window form colour

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to change the window form colour from basic blue to other. Can someone please help how we can do that?
I am seeing only one property of form i.i. formborderstyle.

Comment: I am confused... You talk about Window Form colour but have tagged "ASP .NET"?! What are you using / mean by form colour?

Comment: Normal window form, i have to change the colour i.e blue to green. For eg open window form in visual studio , u will see the blue.

Comment: in asp.net , i am going to make windows app. SO just want to change the color of windows form

Comment: in asp .net window form application ?? how are you gona do it ??

Comment: In visuat studio> Windows form App.

Comment: so this is not asp .net application and i think chris is right

Comment: I want to change the form color

Comment: pls dont get confused OP wants in windows applicatio not in web forms

Answer (score 1):

You can actually change the background colour by adding a CSS inside. May seems a little complicated but it would be very easy  I've done and used this in my project. You may try and refer and see if it helps

CSS tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

My css code in my css file

```
body {
 font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
 background:#FCDFFF; //you can choose the html colour code accordingly
```

}

In your aspx window form page, there should be a body. That body actually links to the body in the css file. Hope this is what you meant. The good point about this is that, you can choose any colour.

[HTML webpage link for CSS colour code.](http://www.computerhope.com/htmcolor.htm)

Comment: there is no body in window forms :(

Comment: do you mind if you paste some code here so it's easier for the community to help you as well. maybe some basic code of the window form. I'm using VS2012, asp.net webform application though

Comment: namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. Use the style property *BODY* or *FORM*

```
<body style="background-color:green; ">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style ="background-color:green;">
        ...
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it but it will not  be easy You have to use P/Invoke for this:

The thing you are trying to achieve is known as Drawing in Non Client Area of Windows Form.

Title Bar(is the place where maximize , minimize , close button resides) of a Windows Form is not in Client Area of it and there is not direct way of painting it.

Anyhow You will get a lot of articles and project on it on Internet here is it:

http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=CustomerBorderForm&title=Painting%20NonClient%20Area

http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=CustomerBorderForm

http://www.geekswithblogs.net/kobush/articles/CustomBorderForms.aspx

http://customerborderform.codeplex.com/releases/view/146

reference taken from :http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/485fb4c5-8430-4cb5-8a4d-ccd7892e403b/how-to-change-the-title-bar-appearance

Answer (score 0):

You can refer these below sites it has lot of information regarding your solution

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288405(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288405%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/165119/How-to-change-the-color-of-Windows-form-header

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/code359-change-the-window-form-color.aspx

http://psycodedeveloper.wordpress.com/2013/01/18/implementing-your-own-colour-themes-in-a-c-windows-forms-application/